# Directory Searcher not returning all the results

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, domaincontroller

I have created 2400 security groups and added all these security groups to the user. When I query Active Directory using a `DirectorySearcher`, I get only 2049 security groups. The remaining security groups are missing. I tried the pagination approach as mentioned below, it still doesn't work. What's the ideal way of getting all the security groups?

```
$gcName = "blahblah.com"
$dn =  "CN=blahblah,OU=Tenants,OU=INT,DC=dom,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=com"
$searchRoot = [ADSI]("LDAP://" + $gcName + "/" + $dn)
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($searchRoot, "(objectClass=*)", @("tokenGroups"), [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::Base)
$searcher.PageSize=500
foreach ($SearchResult  in $searcher.FindAll()){$SearchResult.Properties["tokenGroups"].Count}
```

Edit 1:
When I use the following commands, it doesn't return the complete list of security groups. Ideally, I expect all the groups here along with some other user properties.

```
$searchRoot = [ADSI]("LDAP://" + $gcName)
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($searchRoot, "(|((msOnline-WindowsLiveNetId=xxxxxx))((msOnline-AlternativeSecurityId=YYYYYYYY)))", @("name"))
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("msOnline-UserPrincipalName","objectClass","msOnline-AccountEnabled","displayName","proxyaddresses","memberOf"))
$sr = $searcher.FindOne()
$de= $sr.GetDirectoryEntry()
$de.RefreshCache(@("tokenGroups"))
$de.Properties["tokenGroups"].Count
```

When I use the following, it returns all the groups but I don't get the user properties.

```
$searchRoot = [ADSI]("LDAP://" + $gcName)
$searcher = [adsisearcher]::new($searchRoot, "(&(objectClass=group)(member=$dn))", @("name"))
$searcher.PageSize=500
$searcher.FindAll().Count
```

This doesn't work either.

```
$searchRoot = [ADSI]("LDAP://" + $gcName)
$searcher = [adsisearcher]::new($searchRoot, "((member=$dn))", @("name","msOnline-UserPrincipalName","tokenGroups"))
$searcher.PageSize=500
$searcher.FindAll().Count
```

All I want to achieve is get all the tokenGroups and few user properties with a single search.

Answer (score 1):

The `PageSize` only affects the number of search results, but there is only one search result. You're counting the number of records in the `tokenGroups` attribute of that one result.

One possible issue is that `tokenGroups` will only show security groups, because it is designed for determining the user's permissions. If the user is in any groups where the 'Group type' is "distribution", those will not be included in `tokenGroups`.

If you only have one domain in your AD forest, then you can look at the `memberOf` attribute instead of `tokenGroups`. If you have more than one domain in your forest, then `memberOf` [may not give you all the groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#beware-of-memberof).

You could also change the search so that it looks for all groups that have that user as a member. That would look like this:

```
$gcName = "blahblah.com"
$dn =  "CN=blahblah,OU=Tenants,OU=INT,DC=dom,DC=abc,DC=def,DC=com"
$searchRoot = [ADSI]("LDAP://" + $gcName)
$searcher = [adsisearcher]::new($searchRoot, "(&(objectClass=group)(member=$dn))", @("name"))
$searcher.PageSize=500
$searcher.FindAll().Count
```

Notice that you can use `[adsisearcher]::new` as a short form for `New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher`.

Comment: The query with the new filter just gets the tokenGroups. What I am looking for is the query should return few other user properties along with the right list of tokenGroups.

Comment: The `@("tokenGroups")` is what tells it which attributes to return during the search. So just add whatever other attributes you want to get in that array.

Comment: This doesn't return any results. If I remove the "tokenGroups", it works fine.

Comment: I have just updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: *"doesn't return the complete list of security groups"* - how do you know that?

Comment: I created 2200 security groups and added the user to those groups. Now the query returns only 2049 groups.

Comment: If I use the below query it returns all the groups. [adsisearcher]::new($searchRoot, "(&(objectClass=group)(member=$dn))", @("name"))

Comment: Are all of those groups on the same domain?

Comment: Do you get the same number of results using this query? `[adsisearcher]::new($searchRoot, "(&(objectClass=group)(member=$dn)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))", @("name"))`

Comment: Yes, I get all (2212) groups when I use the above query (groupType).

Comment: Are all the groups on the same domain?

Comment: Yes they are all of the same domain. Is there any server side setting that limits the no. of groups when user object is queried?

Comment: Then I don't know why that's happening. I guess you can't use `tokenGroups`.

Comment: You talk about getting "user properties", but your question is about finding groups. Which are you trying to search for, groups or users?

Comment: I want to query for a user object (one particular user) that will return the tokenGroups along with some other user properties. So, to answer your question, I want to search for both the groups and a user.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `memberOf` instead of `tokenGroups`, like I described in my answer?

Comment: Yes, using the range retrieval on member of, I am able to fetch all the groups but I am interested in security groups only. I rephrased my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142852/the-refreshcache-method-not-returning-the-complete-list-of-tokengroups