# The RefreshCache method not returning the complete list of tokenGroups

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry, directorysearcher

I have created 2400 security groups and made a user member of all these security groups. Now I am trying to fetch all the security groups the user is member of using the DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache method. The method returns only 2050 groups.

```
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($null)
$searcher.SearchRoot = [ADSI]("LDAP://" + $gcName)
$searcher.Filter = "((msOnline-WindowsLiveNetId=XXXXXXXX))"
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("msOnline-UserPrincipalName"))
$sr = $searcher.FindOne()
$de= $sr.GetDirectoryEntry()
$de.RefreshCache(@("tokenGroups"))
$de.Properties["tokenGroups"].Count
```

I tried the range retrieval. Something like below. It still doesn't work.

```
$de.RefreshCache(@("tokenGroups"))
$count = $de.Properties["tokenGroups"].Count
$count
$de.RefreshCache(@("tokenGroups;range=$count-*"))
$de.Properties["tokenGroups"].Count
```

What's the best way to retrieve all the security groups of a user using the RefreshCache method?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where is your loop?

Comment: But apparently you will have more problems than just this if you have one user in so many groups. Read this: [AD: Can you be member of unlimited groups?](https://serverfault.com/q/70415/163227) and this: [Group Memberships for Security Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc756101(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#group-memberships-for-security-principals)

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for looking into this. I have flattened the loop actually. I am querying for maximum records first time and then maximum records to * the next time. See the RefreshCache method twice once without range and once with the range. However your comments on the group limits makes sense.

Comment: How many groups is that showing you?

Comment: It's showing 2050 each time.

Comment: Then that's all you're going to get from `tokenGroups`. There is nothing else to get from that attribute.

Comment: If I explicitly query for the groups using DirectorySearcher with filter UPN and ObjectType -Group, it returns all of them. Is it not possible to do something similar with DirectoryEntry?

Comment: I'm saying that you can't get it from `tokenGroups`. That's what your testing has shown.

Comment: The reason you need range retrieval is because AD will only give you 1500 at a time. The fact that you are getting less than 1500 on the second request means that it doesn't have another 1500 to give you. That means you got everything there is to get in the `tokenGroups` attribute. This possibly has something to do with the limit of groups I linked to above.